# Is there an analog of polarization for skew-symmetric forms?

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, symmetric-functions, multilinear-algebra

This question might be too lightweight here but [on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3654696/214353) it did not receive any feedback since May 2, so...

[Polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_of_an_algebraic_form) works both ways. Not only can you represent any homogeneous polynomial $f$ of degree $d$ as $F(x,...,x)$ for a multilinear form $F(x_1,...,x_d)$ but also conversely, any symmetric multilinear form $F$ is so obtained from the homogeneous polynomial $F(x,...,x)$.

Is there a similar "trade degree for number of variables" trick for multilinear forms which are not symmetric but skew-symmetric? Already the bilinear case would make me happy.

I thought this was possible since there is a "one floor higher" version of polarization, namely linearization of polynomial functors (see e. g. Appendix A in Macdonald's [Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials](https://books.google.com/books?id=srv90XiUbZoC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)), and these involve arbitrary representations of symmetric groups, so one has not only symmetric but also exterior powers in the game. But I have no idea how to "return to the lower floor" from that.

Another thought was to work in a commutative [superalgebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superalgebra), but how exactly?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what kind of result you are looking for. In the anti-symmetric case, $F(x, \ldots, x)=0$, so there is no possible direct analogy  with the symmetric case.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi, what you say is true only if $F$ itself is skew-symmetric, but that doesn't seem to be part of the requirement.  I think maybe part of the confusion is caused by the switch from using $f$ and $F$ as separate objects when describing one direction of polarisation, to apparently using $f$ and $F$ for the same object (am I reading that correctly?).  Anyway, it certainly seems like the ambiguity in the question is deliberate, in the sense that it's not "does this particular analogue of polarisation hold?" but "*what* is the appropriate analogue?".

Comment: Thank you @LSpice for nice formulation. Yes, precisely, I am looking for an appropriate analogue.